# MPMoviePlayer PlaybackEnd notification receive only once

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

My app has a view with Movie Player. Which plays a stream from the internet. I register for MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification to capture failures. I implement custom UI to the player so that user can start the play and pause it. Here is my code

```
-(void)setUpPlayer:(NSURL*)urlForBuffer{

    self.playerVC = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:urlForBuffer];

    // Remove the movie player view controller from the "playback did finish" notification observers
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.playerVC
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:self.playerVC];

    // Register this class as an observer instead
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.playerVC];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moveiPlayBackStateChanged:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object:self.playerVC];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object:self.playerVC];

    [self.playerVC setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
    self.playerVC.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    [self.view addSubview:self.playerVC.view];

}

- (void)movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*)aNotification{
    NSLog(@"stop playing movie file ");
    // Obtain the reason why the movie playback finished
    NSNumber *finishReason = [[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] ;

    if ([finishReason intValue] == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded) {
        //movie finished playin
        NSLog(@"Playback has ended without having an error ");

    }else if ([finishReason intValue] == MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited) {
        //user hit the done button
        NSLog(@"User has clicked done button ");

    }else if ([finishReason intValue] == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError) {
        //error
        NSLog(@"Error has occred while playing moviefile ");

    }

    [self.playerVC stop];
}
```

I want to check MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification notification works fine. So when player streaming I disconnect the wifi. I received the notification movieFinishedCallback: method without any problem. Also in my console it prints following error message as well.

```
_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
    AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeErrorKey = "Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 \"The network connection was lost.\" UserInfo=0xc057da0 {NSUnderlyingError=0xc084ce0 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (OSStatus error -1005.)\", NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.}";
}
```

Then I clicked the play button again while Wifi is off (I have stop the player in movieFinishedCallback:). Then I did not receive any notification. But following error has printed in my console.

```
_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 2;
    old = 0;
}
```

Where did it go wrong. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

There is no file located on the given URL `urlForBuffer` while Wifi is off. So make sure there is a file at the given URL.

Comment: Can you tell me why I did not receive the notification in that case.